# httpd.conf rewriterule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

None of my RewriteRules seem to be working...

I have tried many variations, but none of them seem to be read.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain2.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrapped in VirtualHost tag and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some log ? If not, enabled RewriteLog and use a hight RewriteLogLevel: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Also, don't forget to enable rewrite module.

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

And use a conf like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/website/html>
    Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain2.com$1 [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Which directory should I specify?